# Filling data in form using angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, forms

I am a true beginner at Angular (but not JS), started yesterday, so I hope you forgive me if this question sound stupid. Consider the following small application:

**HTML:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="todoApp">
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/TestController.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="TestController as myControl">
        <div id="overlaybox">
            <button ng-click="myControl.showUpd(4)">Test</button><br/><br/><br/>

            <form ng-submit="myControl.updTodo()">
                Note:<br/>
                <textarea rows="5" cols="30" id="updContent" ng-model="noteupd.content"></textarea><br/>
                Deadline (format YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM):<br/>
                <input type="text" id="updDeadline" ng-model="noteupd.deadline" /><br/>
                Completed: 
                <input type="checkbox" id="updCompleted" ng-model="noteupd.completed" /><br/>
                <input type="hidden" id="updID" ng-model="noteupd.id" /><br/>
                <input type="submit" value="Update" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Angular-controller:**

```
angular.module('todoApp', []).controller('TestController', function($scope, $http) {
    var thisApp = this;

    thisApp.showUpd = function(noteID) {
        $http({method : 'GET', url : 'http://localhost:8000/notes/' + noteID})
            .then (function(response) {
                console.log(response.data.content);
                console.log(response.data.deadline);
                console.log(response.data.id);
                console.log(response.data.completed);

                document.getElementById("updContent").innerHTML = response.data.content;
                document.getElementById("updDeadline").value = response.data.deadline;
                document.getElementById("updID").value = response.data.id;

                if (response.data.completed == 1) {
                    document.getElementById("updCompleted").checked = true;
                } else {
                    document.getElementById("updCompleted").checked = false;
                }
            }, function() {
                alert("Error getting todo note");
            });
    }

    thisApp.updTodo = function(noteupd) {
        console.log("TEST");
        console.log($scope.noteupd);
    }
});
```

After clicking Test-button I get the following output in my console:

- TestController.js:7 123123
- TestController.js:8 2016-01-05 10:28:42
- TestController.js:9 4
- TestController.js:10 0

By then, the fields in the form have been filled in (and the hidden field has a value). And after clicking Update I get this in the console:

- TestController.js:27 TEST
- TestController.js:28 undefined

If i change the values in the fields manually, I do get something else instead of "undefined", but the idea is that one should not have to change the values. Also, the object does not contain the hidden "id" even if all fields are changed.

Obviously, I'm a beginner at this, and obviously I'm doing it wrong, but do anyone have a suggestion on how I can make this work?

Comment: You don't want to use document.getElementById in angular use angular.element("#id") instead

Comment: Also realize angular is 2 way data binding. Meaning if you change the value of your ng-model variable in your code it will change in your html

Comment: And you didn't define noteupd

Comment: @Binvention Tried ti change to `angular.element("#id")` but it didn't work at all, now it doesn't load the data into the fields. Also tried to wrap it as a jQuery object: `angular.element($("#id"))`, it did not work either.

And also, where should I have defined noteupd?

Comment: Try the answer I have below

Comment: Just for future reference the problem with trying to change the values the way you tried is that ng-model doesn't know you changed the values so it over writes it with the blank object that occurs from noteupd not being defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your html is fine but your code needs fixing

First define noteupd in your code

Use noteupd to change your html values rather then document.getElementById

That should fix your code it will end up looking like this

```
angular.module('todoApp', []).controller('TestController', function($scope, $http) {
    var thisApp = this;
    $scope.noteupd={}; //defining noteupd
    var noteupd=$scope.noteupd;  //preventing scope issues
    thisApp.showUpd = function(noteID) {
        $http({method : 'GET', url : 'http://localhost:8000/notes/' + noteID})
            .then (function(response) {
                console.log(response.data.content);
                console.log(response.data.deadline);
                console.log(response.data.id);
                console.log(response.data.completed);

                //updating your html
                 noteupd.content= response.data.content;
                noteupd.deadline = response.data.deadline;
              noteupd.id= response.data.id;

                if (response.data.completed == 1) {
                    noteupd.completed = true;
                } else {
                    noteupd.completed = false;
                }
            }, function() {
                alert("Error getting todo note");
            });
    }

    thisApp.updTodo = function(noteupd) {
        console.log("TEST");
        console.log($scope.noteupd);
    }
});
```

Comment: Ah, now I get it. Thanks @Binvention

Answer (score 0):

If you are using this variable against $scope .. you have always ng-controller with alias ,  and you  can only access properties or methods  of controller   with controller alias only ..

if you didnt use  **ng-controller= "TestController as myController"** 
and not access methods as  myController.method() .. your example won't be worked...(section 2)

Here is some examples to describe you how it is work

Check this tutorial too ..
http://plnkr.co/edit/FgBcahr6WKAI2oEgg4cO?p=preview

```
angular.module('todoApp', []).controller('TestController', function($scope, $http) {
  var thisApp = this;
  $scope.readedTodo = {};
  this.noteupd = {};

  thisApp.showUpd = function(noteID) {
    // changed your url as defat json data 
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'data.json'
      })
      .then(function(response) {
        console.log(response.data);
        console.log(response.data.content);
        console.log(response.data.deadline);
        console.log(response.data.id);
        console.log(response.data.completed);

        thisApp.noteupd = response.data;
        $scope.readedTodo = response.data;




      }, function() {
        alert("Error getting todo note");
      });
  }

  thisApp.updTodo = function(noteupd) {
    console.log("TEST");
    console.log(thisApp.noteupd);
  }
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="todoApp">

<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="overlaybox" ng-controller="TestController as myControl">
    <button ng-click="myControl.showUpd(4)">Test</button>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>


    <form ng-submit="myControl.updTodo()">
      <h3>if you use binding h this against $scope</h3> Note:
      <br/>
      <textarea rows="5" cols="30" id="updContent" ng-model="myController.noteupd.content"></textarea>
      <br/> Deadline (format YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM):
      <br/>
      <input type="text" id="updDeadline" ng-model="myController.noteupd.deadline" />
      <br/> Completed:
      <input type="checkbox" id="updCompleted" ng-model="myController.noteupd.completed" />
      <br/>


      <h3>if you use binding with $scope</h3> Note:

      <br/>
      <textarea rows="5" cols="30" id="updContent2" ng-model="readedTodo.content"></textarea>
      <br/> Deadline (format YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM):
      <br/>
      <input type="text" id="updDeadline222" ng-model="readedTodo.deadline" />
      <br/> Completed:
      <input type="checkbox" id="updCompleted" ng-model="readedTodo.completed" />
      <br/>
      <input type="hidden" id="updID" ng-model="readedTodo.id" />
      <br/>
      <input type="submit" value="Update" />
    </form>
  </div>


  <h3>SEction 2 </h3>
    <div id="overlaybox2" ng-controller="TestController ">
    <button ng-click="showUpd(4)">Test</button>
    <button ng-click="showUpdate(4)">Test</button>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>


    <form ng-submit="updTodo()">
      <h3>if you use binding h this against $scope</h3> Note:
      <br/>
      <textarea rows="5" cols="30" id="updContent" ng-model="readedTodo.content"></textarea>
      <br/> Deadline (format YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM):
      <br/>
      <input type="text" id="updDeadline" ng-model="readedTodo.deadline" />
      <br/> Completed:
      <input type="checkbox" id="updCompleted" ng-model="readedTodo.completed" />
      <br/>


      <h3>if you use binding with $scope</h3> Note:

      <br/>
      <textarea rows="5" cols="30" id="updContent2" ng-model="readedTodo.content"></textarea>
      <br/> Deadline (format YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM):
      <br/>
      <input type="text" id="updDeadline222" ng-model="readedTodo.deadline" />
      <br/> Completed:
      <input type="checkbox" id="updCompleted" ng-model="readedTodo.completed" />
      <br/>
      <input type="hidden" id="updID" ng-model="readedTodo.id" />
      <br/>
      <input type="submit" value="Update" />
    </form>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You can very well still use the $scope when you've used controller as. They dont conflict. All controller as does is add a object to the scope that is attached to the this object in your controller

Comment: nope you didnt understand .. if you define function with  this.Method = function you have to use alias ..  to access it .. i was trying to tell that ..

Comment: And variables attached to $scope are available within the controller without using any sort of parent object. Controller as defines a new object on the scope the scope is where all of the variables available in the controller are. $scope attaches variables to the scope itself. This attaches variables to the alias

Comment: The way he had it originally was fine as far as his scopes go

Comment: All of the functions he attached to this he properly used the alias

Comment: "I am a true beginner at Angular (but not JS), started yesterday" ... i was trying to tell him the differecence .. with  this.method defination and $scope method defination and gave an example to clear .. and said  the same what you are writing here .. if he dont use alias  for controller .. he can't  access the method which is defined with 'this.' ...

Comment: Thanks for the clarification just for future reference answers should be relating directly to the question. Scopes weren't his problem so an answer on scopes doesn't really add anything to this question.